# If every three segments from set have common interesecting line, than there exist line passing through all segments from this set

Tags: combinatorial-geometry, convex-geometry

There are given lines segments in a plane such that for any three of them 
there exists a line intersecting them. Prove that there exists a line intersecting all these segments.
Perhaps I should use Helly's Theorem, but I have no idea how.
In one source I found easier version of this problem (with additional assumptions that set of segments is finite and all segments are parallel), but I can't do that too (I think in this case I should do that by induction and after that apply this result to the infinite case).

Comment: It would improve your Question if you give the source of (the hard version of) this problem.  Perhaps the assumption of finitely many segments can be removed by a compactness argument.

Comment: I found this in several sources (I think it is from some contest), but only one I can find now is this http://www.mathteacherscircle.org/assets/session-materials/TShubin%28Mostly%29Simple%28MostlyArea%29ProblemswithSolutions.pdf             Easier version is from article that is not in english.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is false.

Consider the four black line segments in this picture:

[image]

There is a line intersecting any three of them — the red lines — but I don't believe there is any line intersecting all four segments.

Comment: It seems you are right, but this is completely surprising for me, I believed this statement to be true.